# What is meant by saying the work done by a conservative force is -(change in PE)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, potential-energy, conventions

I read through all related questions, and they are almost the same, but I still didn't understand this and so am asking again.

What is meant when we say that the work done by conservative force is = -(Change in PE)? How can we say that a conservative force is defined in this way?
What about the work done by a pseudo force?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conservative force is one whose done work depends only on the initial and final states of the body it acts on, the energy associated with which is the state's potential energy.

An illustration:
 Gravity is a conservative force. So the work done by it is dependent on the initial and final states (in this case, height from the earth's surface) of the body it acts on. The energy associated with these states are the respective gravitational potential energies. The work done by gravity is the work required to change the state of the body from the initial to the final one, which is given by the difference in initial and final gravitational potential energies.

Change in kinetic energy is ignored as in both initial and final states, the body is at rest.

A similar logic can be applied for electrostatic forces and other conservative forces too.
A pseudo force not being a real force can do no work. However, if the frame of reference is shifted to one in which an equivalent real force acts, we can find the work done by that force, and so transform it into the supposed work done by the pseudo force

Comment: Ok it's clear for gravitational, but what about in general for any conservative force? Why does the WD by a conservative force equal loss in PE? I can understand about the fact that only final and initial positions are involved, but what about KE change then?

Comment: Ok makes more sense now. Yes, I see why the work done equals the change in Potential Energy. But what about the Kinetic Energy change? Why is that ignored?

Comment: "Change in kinetic energy is ignored as in both initial and final states, the body is at rest." - How can we say that? Let's say a body was at a ht of 10m. Then it came down to 4m, under no force other than gravity. So a conservative force acted upon it, and the work done was 6mg, which is equal to -(4mg - 10mg), but the body has gained a certain velocity. What I now understand is that the work done will always be equal to -(Change in PE) (thanks - your explanation), but even if there is a KE change, it doesn't matter, the value of the WD will only be equal to -(PE change). Is that right?

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely correct. There is no change in kinetic energy between the initial and final states.

Comment: Why not? Sorry I'm confused.